# How do you export a prop name and the type instead of defining it everywhere?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Say I have something like this:

```
export type Style = Pick<
  React.CSSProperties,
  "margin" | "marginBottom"
>
```

and I can then use in a component like

```
type Props = {
   style: Style
}
```

but instead of having to define that in EVERY component I'd rather do

```
type Props = {
  someRandomProp
} & Style
```

and that way I don't need to add the prop as a type everywhere

how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it very nearly as you've shown:

```typescript
export type Style = Pick<
    React.CSSProperties,
    "margin" | "marginBottom"
>;
export type StyleProp = {
    style: Style
};
```

then

```typescript
import { StyleProp } from "./somewhere";
// ...
type Props = {
    someRandomProp: string; // or whatever
} & StyleProp;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljhgE8wk4BlJgG1YF44AFYGgDWAHnJxJiYjAB0AYTZt+OFrGBIAzgBoJU-CBRQA5sAB2+OAB8Chk+YBCEGDFz5yAPgo068Ji3YuJBUIMDg+AG89SU0ggC5Axm5yAF8Kcn9WELBNcLgoqThNXCQEFDMAE1xshNioc2MKFLgAMkTubNIgA)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the oficial documentation: [Typescript Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces)

```
type Animal = {
  name: string
}

type Bear = Animal & { 
  honey: boolean 
}
```

You can also use interfaces instead of types for each component and make them extend from the original predefined type like this:

```
type Animal = {
  name: string
}

interface Bear extends Animal {
  honey: boolean
}
```

Notice that extending doesn't work between types or from an interface to a type. Only interfaces and classes may extend from another entity.